# Modifying save() in django model keeps looping

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a model based on the Google Map API.

If the object does not exists, I want to save the name, address, longitude, latitude and google place ID. Below is my code: However, when I run it, it goes into a loop and does stop checking Google Map. Can you tell me what is wrong?

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    logitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    id_google = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(_('date created'), default=timezone.now)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(_('date_modified'), auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            place = Place.objects.get(name=self.name)
        except Place.DoesNotExist:
            gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=settings.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
            geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(self.address)
            place = Place(name=self.name, 
                        address=geocode_result[0]['formatted_address'],
                        logitude=geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lng'],
                        latitude=geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lat'],
                        id_google=geocode_result[0]['place_id'], 
                        )
            place.save()
        return place
```

Comment: Well you have overwritten `Place.save()` but now in your function, you call `place.save()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `place.save()` in the `save(..)` method, and thus triggering another save. You probably can just edit the item inplace, and then save it by using a `super().save()` call:

```
class Place(models.Model):

    # ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            place = Place.objects.get(name=self.name)
        except Place.DoesNotExist:
            gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=settings.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
            geocode_result = gmaps.geocode(self.address)[0]
            self.address = geocode_result['formatted_address']
            location = geocode_result['geometry']['location']
            self.logitude = location['lng']
            self.latitude = location['lat']
            self.id_google = geocode_result['place_id']
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```